# Checking to see if the fields of multiple ORM relationships contain a value

Tags: python, orm, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Request (the object I am searching) which is made of a User that a Role is being assigned to, represented by said Request. See below:

```
class Request(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'requests'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("users.id"), nullable=False)
    role = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("roles.id"), nullable=False)
    ...
```

And our relationships:

```
# Define relationship between a User and their Requests
requests = relationship('Request', backref='requested_by', lazy='dynamic')

# Define relationship between a Role and Requests for this Role
requests = relationship('Request', backref='requested_role', lazy='dynamic')
```

And finally, the goal:

```
# Return any requests made by a user or a role matching the search query
data = Request.query.filter(or_(Request.requested_by.name.contains(search_query),
                                Request.requested_by.username.contains(search_query),
                                Request.requested_role.name.contains(search_query))).all()
```

Running the above code results in the following:

```
AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with Request.requested_by has an attribute 'name'
```

The idea here being to be able to search Request objects by the relevant details of the User or the Role associated with them. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You need to do a join:

```
Request.query.join(Request.requested_by) \
             .join(Request.requested_role) \
             .filter(or_(User.name.contains(search_query),
                         User.username.contains(search_query),
                         Role.name.contains(search_query)))
```

Note that this produces `LIKE '%whatever%'` queries, which are incredibly inefficient if you have a large table.

Comment: Are there any better ways of approaching a search of these tables, performance-wise? Thanks for the answer

Comment: @JTApps Depends on your particular case, but if you don't want to change how you're querying, you may look into [`pg_trgm`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/pgtrgm.html). [Full-text search](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch.html) is another approach, but it might not work well for usernames.

Comment: Are both of these solutions limited to PostgreSQL?

Comment: @JTApps Sorry, I assumed you were using PostgreSQL. Other RDBMSs usually have full-text capabilities, e.g. [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html) and [SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx). Please note that full-text search usually indexes words, so searching for arbitrary substring usually doesn't work well. You may also want to look into a dedicated search backend, e.g. [ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/).

Comment: Currently using SQLite and will be transitioning to Oracle post development. Hopefully I can find a valid solution, as the tables being searched are relatively large.